# Update AFNetworking from version 1.2.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, afnetworking

Iam about to update our post project in Objective C to meet the new Apple requirement for support Ipv6 only. My `AFNetworking` libray is now 1.2.1. I doubt it is the problem. I want to update to latest version support IPv6 but when running pod install I get this error

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (~> 3.1.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (= 3.1.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.2.1)` required by `AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation (1.0.2)`

Here is my complete pod file

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

def shared_pods
    pod 'RaptureXML'
    pod 'Realm'
end

def ios_pods

    pod 'AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.9'
    pod 'KGModal', '~> 0.0.1'
    pod 'MagicalRecord'
    pod 'MHNatGeoViewControllerTransition', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'UALogger', '~> 0.2.3'
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
    pod 'RegexKitLite', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2.1'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'UIAlertView+Blocks', '~> 0.7'
    pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage', '~> 1.0.3'
    pod 'SevenSwitch', '~> 1.3.0'
    pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'DeviceUtil', '~> 1.2'
end
```

Is there any way to use `AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation` with AFNetworking 3.0? or any other solution? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any alternative way that support AFNetworking 3.x?

Comment: Thanks i will try it. Do you have any reference link or any tutorial regarding the AFXMLParserResponseSerializer?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation` subclasses `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, but this class no longer exists in AFNetworking 3.x. You will not be able to use `AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation` with AFNetworking 3.x.

If you're just parsing `XML` response with AFNetworking 3.x, you can use `AFXMLParserResponseSerializer`. It returns a `NSXMLParser`.

So, set the `delegate` for that `responseObject`, and then call `parse` on it:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/rss+xml"];  // this line is only needed if parsing RSS feed

[manager GET:@"https://developer.apple.com/news/rss/news.rss" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *parser = responseObject;
    parser.delegate = self;
    self.titles = [NSMutableArray array];
    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.titles);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

You'll have to write your own `NSXMLParserDelegate` code, though. So, to parse the titles out of the XML of Apple's RSS feed, I added two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *titles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *elementValue;
```

And then implemented the following `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,NSString *> *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        self.elementValue = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    [self.elementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [self.titles addObject:self.elementValue];
        self.elementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I try again. My problem is to upgrade these manager to work with AFNetworking 3.x. Can you help to look at these file and suggest any change to migrate? many thanks! !https://1drv.ms/f/s!At_ezahqccq3it1dbThVHBz9hok1xw

Comment: You have to replace `AFHTTPClient` with `AFHTTPSessionManager`, and replace your `AFHTTPRequestOperation` with `GET` and `POST` calls (as appropriate). And, as outlined above, you have to replace `AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation` with `GET`/`POST` with `AFXMLParserResponseSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still struggle with these migration. Can help take a look at actual method here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580561/afnetworking-3-x-migration-and-xml-parser