# AFNetworking 3.x Migration and XML parser

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, afnetworking

Hi I'm about to upgrade old project that use `AFNetworking` 1.2.1 and `AFRaptureXMLOperation` to AFNetworking 3.1 to meet to ipv6 requirement from Apple. But because `AFRaptureXMLOperation` is not support for `AFNetworking` 3.1 Is there anyway to convert and parse JSON, XML? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

this my ApiClient.h

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation.h>
#import <RXMLElement.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@class Stamp;

@interface ApiClient : AFHTTPClient

+(BOOL)isScanner;
+(BOOL)isWithoutFacebook;

typedef void (^ApiClientSuccess)(id responseObject);
typedef void (^ApiClientFailure)(NSError *error);
typedef void (^ApiClientProgressCompletion)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations);

+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance;

- (void)reportAPIIssueURL:(NSString *)url payload:(NSString *)payload message:(NSString *)message;

//informations
- (void)getSingpostContentsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getSendReceiveItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getPayItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getShopItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getServicesItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getSingPostAppsItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getOffersItemsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getSingpostAnnouncementSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success failure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//calculate postage
- (void)calculateSingaporePostageForFromPostalCode:(NSString *)fromPostalCode andToPostalCode:(NSString *)toPostalCode andWeight:(NSString *)weightInGrams onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)calculateOverseasPostageForCountryCode:(NSString *)countryCode andWeight:(NSString *)weightInGrams andItemTypeCode:(NSString *)itemTypeCode andDeliveryCode:(NSString *)deliveryCode onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//postal codes
- (void)findPostalCodeForBuildingNo:(NSString *)buildingNo andStreetName:(NSString *)streetName onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)findPostalCodeForLandmark:(NSString *)landmark onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)findPostalCodeForWindowsDeliveryNo:(NSString *)windowsDeliveryNo andType:(NSString *)type andPostOffice:(NSString *)postOffice onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//locations
- (void)getPostOfficeLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getSamLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getPostingBoxLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getPostalAgentLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getSingPostAgentLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getPopStationLocationsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

- (void)getLocationsUpdatesOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getLocationsUpdatesDetails:(NSArray *)array
                           success:(ApiClientSuccess)success
                           failure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//tracking
- (void)getItemTrackingDetailsForTrackingNumber:(NSString *)trackingNumber onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)batchUpdateTrackedItems:(NSArray *)trackedItems onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure withProgressCompletion:(ApiClientProgressCompletion)progressCompletion;

//notifications
- (void)registerAPNSToken:(NSString *)apnsToken onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)subscribeNotificationForTrackingNumber:(NSString *)trackingNumber onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)subscribeNotificationForTrackingNumberArray:(NSArray *)trackingNumberArray onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)unsubscribeNotificationForTrackingNumber:(NSString *)trackingNumber onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)unsubscribeNotificationForTrackingNumberArray:(NSArray *)trackingNumberArray onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//philately
- (void)getStampsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void)getImagesOfStamp:(Stamp*)stamp onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//misc
- (void)getMaintananceStatusOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//feedback
- (void)postFeedbackMessage:(NSString *)message subject:(NSString *)subject onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//App update checking
- (void)checkAppUpdateWithAppVer:(NSString *)appVer andOSVer:(NSString *)osVer;

//Ad Banner
-(void) getAdvertisementWithId : (NSString *)locationMasterId Count:(NSString *)count onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
-(void) incrementClickCountWithId: (NSString *)locationId onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;

//Tracking Labeling
- (void) facebookLoginOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void) isFirstTime:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void) registerTrackingNunmbers: (NSArray *)numbers WithLabels : (NSArray *)labels TrackDetails : (NSArray *) details onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void) registerTrackingNunmbersNew: (NSArray *)numbers WithLabels : (NSArray *)labels TrackDetails : (RLMResults *) details onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void) getAllTrackingNunmbersOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;
- (void) deleteAllTrackingNunmbersOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure;


@property (nonatomic) NSString * serverToken;
@property (nonatomic,retain) RLMResults * allTrackingItem;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * fbToken;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * fbID;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL hasRegisteredProfileId;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *notificationProfileID;

@end
```

Top line of My ApiClient.m

```
#import "ApiClient.h"
#import "EntityLocation.h"
#import "Stamp.h"
#import <SSKeychain.h>
#import "UIAlertView+Blocks.h"
#import "NSDictionary+Additions.h"
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import "DeliveryStatus.h"
#import "Parcel.h"

#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

@implementation ApiClient
@synthesize serverToken;
@synthesize fbToken;
@synthesize allTrackingItem;
@synthesize fbID;

@synthesize notificationProfileID = _notificationProfileID;

static BOOL isProduction = YES;
static BOOL isScanner = YES;
static BOOL isWithoutFacebook = NO;

+(BOOL)isScanner {
    return  isScanner;
}

+(BOOL)isWithoutFacebook {
    return  isWithoutFacebook;
}

#define SINGPOST_BASE_URL   (isProduction ? SINGPOST_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL:SINGPOST_UAT_BASE_URL)
#define CMS_BASE_URL        (isProduction ? CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL:CMS_UAT_BASE_URL)
#define CMS_BASE_URL_V4     (isProduction ? CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL_V4:CMS_UAT_BASE_URL_V4)
#define AD_BASE_URL         (isProduction ? AD_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL : AD_UAT_BASE_URL)

//Development
static NSString *const SINGPOST_UAT_BASE_URL = @"https://uatesb1.singpost.com";
static NSString *const CMS_UAT_BASE_URL = @"http://27.109.106.170/mobile2/";
static NSString *const CMS_UAT_BASE_URL_V4 = @"http://27.109.106.170/mobile2/v5/";
static NSString *const AD_UAT_BASE_URL = @"https://uat.mysam.sg/restful-services/advertisementServices/";

//Production
static NSString *const SINGPOST_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"https://prdesb1.singpost.com";
static NSString *const CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"http://mobile.singpost.com/mobile2/";
static NSString *const CMS_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL_V4 = @"http://mobile.singpost.com/mobile2/v5/";
static NSString *const AD_PRODUCTION_BASE_URL = @"https://www.mysam.sg/restful-services/advertisementServices/";

static NSString *const APP_ID = @"M00002";
static NSString *const OS = @"ios";

//Tracking testing URL
//static NSString * const TRACKING_TEST_URL = @"https://prdesb1.singpost.com/ma/GetItemTrackingDetailsCentralTnT";
//static NSString * const TRACKING_TEST_URL = @"https://uatesb1.singpost.com/ma/GetItemTrackingDetailsCentralTnT";

#pragma mark - Shared singleton instance

+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL]];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ((self = [super initWithBaseURL:url])) {
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Properties

- (BOOL)hasRegisteredProfileId
{
    return [[self notificationProfileID] length] > 0;
}

- (NSString *)notificationProfileID
{
    if (!_notificationProfileID) {
        _notificationProfileID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:KEYCHAIN_SERVICENAME account:@"SETTINGS_PROFILEID"];
    }
    return _notificationProfileID;
}

- (void)setNotificationProfileID:(NSString *)inNotificationProfileID
{
    if (inNotificationProfileID.length > 0) {
        _notificationProfileID = inNotificationProfileID;
        [SSKeychain setPassword:_notificationProfileID forService:KEYCHAIN_SERVICENAME account:@"SETTINGS_PROFILEID"];
    }
}
```

And Some of my ApiClient.m that Parse Json and XML

```
#pragma mark - API calls

#pragma mark - Informations

- (void)getSingpostContentsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"singpost-contents.php"
                                                                              relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CMS_BASE_URL]]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        if (success)
            success(JSON);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        if (failure)
            failure(error);
        [self reportAPIIssueURL:[request.URL absoluteString] payload:nil message:[error description]];
    }];
    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

for xml:

```
#pragma mark - Calculate Postage

- (void)calculateSingaporePostageForFromPostalCode:(NSString *)fromPostalCode
                                   andToPostalCode:(NSString *)toPostalCode
                                         andWeight:(NSString *)weightInGrams
                                         onSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success
                                         onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure {
    NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SingaporePostalInfoDetailsRequest xmlns=\"http://singpost.com/paw/ns\">"
                     "<ToPostalCode>%@</ToPostalCode>"
                     "<FromPostalCode>%@</FromPostalCode>"
                     "<Weight>%@</Weight>"
                     "<DeliveryServiceName></DeliveryServiceName>"
                     "</SingaporePostalInfoDetailsRequest>", toPostalCode, fromPostalCode, weightInGrams];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"ma/FilterSingaporePostalInfo" parameters:nil];
    [request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [xml length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, RXMLElement *XMLElement) {
        if (success)
            success(XMLElement);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, RXMLElement *XMLElement) {
        if (failure)
            failure(error);
        [self reportAPIIssueURL:[request.URL absoluteString] payload:xml message:[error description]];
    }];

    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: We've outlined some of the issues in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38574520/1271826. I think you need to take a stab at this yourself. We're happy to help you if you encounter problems, we really are, but we're not here to write your code for you. So, take it a step at a time, figure out how to do a request in AFNetworking 3.x. Then figure out how to use `NSXMLParser`. Etc. But this question is too broad as it now stands.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still trying but in the template of AFNetworking 3.x. The class use is AFURLSessionManager instead of AFHTTPSesssionManager. When to use each. I have start a question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602385/afnetworking-3-x-what-is-the-different-between-afhttpsessionmanager-and-afurlses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest to use TABXML for XML Parsing since its the faster one . this is the api github link [TBXML Parser](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML)

this is a function that i used to get xml data with TBXML Parser it may help you to understand more . u need just to import

```
#import "TBXML+HTTP.h"
#import "TBXML.h"


-(void)loadnews:(TBXMLElement *)element{

    TBXMLElement *item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:element];

    do {
        TBXMLElement *titre = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:item];
        TBXMLElement *desc = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"description" parentElement:item];





        TBXMLElement *imgitem = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"enclosure" parentElement:item];


        News *myitem=[[News alloc] init];
        myitem.titre=[TBXML textForElement:titre];
        myitem.desc=[TBXML textForElement:desc];


        if(imgitem){
            myitem.img=[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"url" forElement:imgitem];

        }
        else {
            myitem.img=@"noimg";

        }












        [self.mytabnews addObject:myitem];



    } while ((item = item->nextSibling));

    //[self.tablenews performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
    //      withObject:nil
    //  waitUntilDone:NO];}

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tablenews reloadData];
    });
}
```

And for Json parsing using AFnetworking 3.x this function can help you :

```
   -(void) loadevents{

        NSString *path = @"yourapilinkhere";
        NSString *escapedPath = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];



[manager GET:escapedPath parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
            //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'' try yours. Do you know how to send xml request and receive XML response using AFNetworking 3.x as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596162/send-post-request-with-xml-body-and-recieve-xml-response-with-afnetworking-3-x