# AFNetworking 3.x what is the different between AFHTTPSessionManager and AFURLSessionManager?

Tags: json, xml, afnetworking, afhttpsessionmanager

I'm about to upgrade `AFNetworking` from 1.x to 3.x. My question is what is the different between `AFHTTPSessionManager` and `AFURLSessionManager`? and when to use each? Which one support both `XML` and `JSON` request and response? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You generally use `AFHTTPSessionManager` if you want to do `GET` or `POST` requests that might include preparation of JSON or `x-www-formurlencoded` requests or parsing of complex responses. You can get away with `AFURLSessionManager` if you're doing very simple requests for which you don't need any of the additional `AFHTTPSessionManager` capabilities.

Bottom line, `AFHTTPSessionManager` is just a subclass of `AFURLSessionManager` with some richer creation of complex requests and/or parsing of complex responses. Based upon your question (parsing XML and JSON responses), `AFHTTPSessionManager` is what you want to use.